Finding the optimum values that minimize a function containing logarithmic expression.
I want to find the optimum values of $\{p_k \geq 0\}_{k=1}^{K}$ that minimize the following equation
\begin{equation}
L(p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_K)=
\sum_{k=1}^{K} p_{k}+
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{q_k}{log_2{\left(1+\frac{p_k}{a_{k}+\sum_{j\neq k}^{K}p_j }\right)}}
\end{equation}
where $q_k,a_k >0$. This also can be written as
\begin{equation}
L(p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_K)=
\sum_{k=1}^{K} p_{k}+
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{q_k}{log_2{\left(1+\frac{p_k}{a_{k} -p_k+\sum_{j= 1}^{K}p_j}\right)}}
\end{equation}
I draw that for $K=2$, and the equation look convex for  $\{p_1,p_2\}$.

Can the optimum values of $\{p_k \}_{k=1}^{K}$ found analytically? If not, is there a good approximation for the logarithmic function in the equation that would make the solution easier? Thank you for helping me solving this problem.

Sounds like a problem from communication systems. Power and SINR joint optimization. what is your thought and how did you try?
